# Компиляция fat jar maven (Error: Could not find or load main class)

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar

Пытаюсь сделать `fat jar` посредством `mvn clean compile assembly::single`. Однако сам `jar`'ник выдает ошибку:

```
Error: could not find or load main class
```

Структура проекта представлена ниже. В манифесте пробовал прописывать `model.Testing`, `src.main.java.model.Testing`, `main.java.model.Testing`. При открытии архива `jar`, класс присутствует по пути `src/main/java/model/Testing`, но с расширением `.java`! Файлов `.class` я нигде не нашел (хотя при компиляции в папке `target` они создаются).

Если вместо `assembly::single` сделать `assembly::assembly` выводит ошибку:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components is missing...
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Model</groupId>
    <artifactId>Testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>model.Testing</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>model.Testing</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar_with_dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>model.Testing</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        model.Testing
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>model.Testing</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете собрать свой проект с помощью `Maven` из вашей IDE, подключив дополнительные зависимости:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

<sup>См. [«How to export JavaFX 11 Project into Jar»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942815/11141611).</sup>